# MEF Metadata ensure class implements interface stated in Metadata attribute

Tags: c#, .net, interface, mef

Hi I have a a MEF container which detects metadata attributes and I would like to expand on this and allow classes to implement additional intefaces (in the example below, where i want to implement an additional interface IPluginSettings).

The module GUID identifier is critical as it is reconciled with a module ID in my database application, if I query the MEF container for my imported interfaces I can loop through them:

```
foreach (Lazy<T,IPluginMetadata> moduleInAssembly in m_Container.GetExports<T, IPluginMetadata>();)
{
  T value = moduleInAssembly.Value; // instantiate an object of type T to test for implementations of other interfaces...
  if (value is IPluginSettings)
  {
      // this module also contains an interface for settings!
  }
  Guid moduleInAssemblyId = Guid.Parse(moduleInAssembly.Metadata.PluginID);
}
```

I have some questions:

1) In the above scenario, I have to instantiate the class to test if I it implements a specific interface, is there a better way of doing this with Metadata and enhance the PluginExportAttribute to accept a list of secondary interface types?

2) How can I tell MEF container to import types that only have the PluginExportAttribute?

3) Or instead of having each plugin interface flexilbe/free to declare its own interface, would i be better off for plugins to implement a well-known plugin interface which contained a factory to instantiate the specific plugin interface? (Example of what i am asking is at the bottom of the code - last section)

4) Thanks to one proposed answer i am using code structured as per question 4 snipit below and it works! Out of curiosity, is there anyway to merge multiple seperate Export attributes into the PluginExportAttribute, perhaps in a constructor parameter to take a list of additional types to register?

Thanks,

Chris

```
public interface IPluginMetadata
{
    string PluginID { get; }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PluginExportAttribute : ExportAttribute, IPluginMetadata
{
    public PluginExportAttribute(Type t, string guid)
        : base(t)
    {
        PluginID = guid.ToUpper();
    }

    public string PluginID { get; set; }
}


[PluginExport(typeof(IAccountsPlugin),"BE112EA1-1AA1-4B92-934A-9EA8B90D622C")]
public class BillingModule : IAccountsPlugin, IPluginSettings
{
   // my class contents
}
```

**or would i be better of doing something like this...?**

```
// or would i be better of by implementing a plugin base, and getting instances of the plugin via a secondary factory?
public interface IWellKnownPluginBase
{
    Guid PluginID { get; }
    Version Version { get; }
    IPluginSettings Settings { get; }
    Type GetPluginInterfaceType { get; }
    object PluginInterfaceFactory();
}

public interface IMyPlugin
{
    void DoSomethingCool();
}

[Export(typeof(IWellKnownPluginBase))] 
public class MyPluginWrapper : IWellKnownPluginBase
{
    private readonly string ID = "BE112EA1-1AA1-4B92-934A-9EA8B90D622C";

    Guid PluginID { get { return Guid.Parse(ID); } }
    Version Version { get {return new Version(1,0,0); } }
    IPluginSettings Settings { get { return new SomethingThatImplementsIPluginSettings(); }
    Type GetPluginInterfaceType { get { return gettype(IMyPlugin); }
    object PluginInterfaceFactory() { return new MyPlugin(); }

    class MyPlugin : IMyPlugin
    {
        void DoSomethingCool() {}
    }
}
```

**Question 4 - can PluginExport be rewritten to register multiple interfaces with a list of interfaces in the constructor?**

```
[Export(typeof(IPluginSettings))]
[PluginExport(typeof(IAccountsPlugin),"BE112EA‌​1-1AA1-4B92-934A-9EA8B90D622C")]
public MyModule class : IModule, IPluginSettings
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the above scenario, I have to instantiate the class to test if I it implements a specific interface, is there a better way of doing this with Metadata and enhance the PluginExportAttribute to accept a list of secondary interface types?

Normally you would do this by having multiple exports:

```
[Export(typeof(IPluginSettings))]
[Export(typeof(IModule))]
public class MyModule : IModule, IPluginSettings
{
}
```

Instead of checking whether an interface is present, the consumer (i.e. the importer, or in your case the caller of `GetExports`) can then just ask for the correct interface.

Comment: Hi Wim, thanks that works - is there any way this can be merged into the single attribute, i have modified my original questions list and added a final one question 4. Apart from that, i think thats it solved.

Comment: @g18c: as far as I know, no. One export attribute exports one contract.